# Find the parent node of 2 children

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I want to find the 1st common parent node of 2 seperate children.
Let's say i have this structure:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="results">
        <div id="test1">
            <p> 1st result </P>
            <p> test </p>
        </div>
        <div id="test2">
            <p> 2nd result </p>
            <p> test </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How do i automaticaly find the parent div that contains both the `1st result` and the `2nd result`

Comment: @Andersson Nothing yet since i dont know how to do it, i am still looking for  way to do it.

Comment: You need to make at least some efforts to solve your problem... You didn't try anything at all?

Comment: I have been thinking of searching through the whole html doc from the top and find the last node that contains both the results i want but thats not efficient